# Selenium Webdriver 3.5.0 + Geckodriver 0.18.0 + FireFox v55 - Page Reset, Selenium Stop Working

Tags: selenium, firefox, geckodriver

Good morning, afternoon, evening, and thereafter;

I am working on prototyping a site target with an existing site "softwaresupport.hpe.com".  I have put to together a simple python Selenium script, nothing fancy, just stepping through the actions:

From the Element Inspector:

```
<li class="hpswproduct_vl_li" value="1157">
<input id="product11" class="test" name="products" value="operations manager 
i" type="checkbox">
<label class="checkbox ajaxcheckbox" for="product11">operations manager i 
(1157)</label>
</li>
```

from selenium import webdriver

```
driverFF = webdriver.Firefox()
driverFF.get('https://softwaresupport.hpe.com/')
btn1 = driverFF.find_element_by_xpath(".//*
[@id='p_p_id_56_INSTANCE_qLlPrxAvnCX5_']/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/input")
btn1.click()
driverFF.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys("<That_CHEF_Guy_Using_Selenium>@gmail.com")
driverFF.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys('XXXXXXX')
btn2 = driverFF.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='loginsubmitbtn']/span")
btn2.click()

btn3 = driverFF.find_element_by_xpath(".//*
[@id='p_p_id_56_INSTANCE_8IZZyiJiLBeP_']/div/div/div[1]/div/a/img")
btn3.click()

chkbx1 = driverFF.find_element_by_xpath(".//*
[@id='hpswproduct_vl']/li[1]/label")
chkbx1.click()
chkbx3 = driverFF.find_element_by_xpath(".//*
[@id='hpswversion_vl']/li[3]/label")
chkbx3.click()
```

Add this point the whole page reconfigure to present a filter list of 
choices.  Even though the URL does not change, it's as if the new 
configuration of the page is different (Or the focus is lost from the previous page) than would the Selenium Script was controlling. This is why I attempted to use the implicitly_wait(30) assuming the session was still active as the first.

```
driverFF.implicitly_wait(30)
```

The scripts stops after this point.

```
chkarrow1 = driverFF.find_element_by_xpath(".//*
[@id='hpswproduct_vl']/li[3]/label")
chkarrow1.click()

#chkbx3 = driverFF.find_element_by_xpath(".//*
[@id='hpswversion_vl']/li[16]/label")
#chkbx3.click()
```

Is there some additional Selenium magic which I need?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Oh, sorry.  There is no error.  It just completes with exit 0.  An error would have helped give me a place to start looking.

Comment: Try using explicit wait. Using implicit wait is a bad practice. Little bit of googling will help you out.

Comment: Interesting, I thought that  I tread that it was the other way around.  I will give it a try.

Comment: I tried the explicit wait with no success.  I have added the sample of code that I am trying to target at the top as I am now trying to use the ".find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, . . .)"

Comment: Regarding the find element statement, I am thinking something like: 

chkbx3 = driverFF.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.hpswproduct_v1 li.hpswproduct_vl_li #product11 label.checkbox.ajaxcheckbox")